# This email code works but fails to redirect to the referrer page

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I am using wordpress and using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class. This successfully sends emails with an attachment as intended. The issue is it is not redirecting back to the page where the form is. The page where the form is a normal wordpress template page.

```
global $wpdb;
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

get_template_part( 'email/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer');

$testvar = $_POST['test'];
$bodytext = 'Here is a value in the variable...'.$testvar;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'someone@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Spider Man';
$email->Subject   = 'This is the subject of the message';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = get_template_directory().'/images/test.pdf';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'test.pdf' );

return $email->Send();

$Referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header('Location: '. $Referer );
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="Path/to/email_test.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo 'BAZINGA';?>">
 <input type="submit" value="SEND EMAIL">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return $email->Send();` Aren't you returning before it even gets to the `$Referer page` line?

Comment: I thought `header('Location: '. $Referer );` should be the last line to be executed..?? Perhas you are right.

Comment: Place it before your return.  I'm not a php programmer but Perl programmer.  But somehow it looks very familiar.  Once you hit `return` anything after that is dead code.